# Block table colomn with color according date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

in this case I want to block the table cells with color according the booking status and check in / check out date. For example I have this on databases:

```
reservationID | guestName | villaName  | roomName | checkIn    | checkOut   | status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RSV01         | John      | Villa ABCD | Unit 1   | 2019-04-01 | 2019-04-05 | Confirmed
RSV02         | Mike      | Villa ABCD | Unit 1   | 2019-04-05 | 2019-04-09 | On Hold
```

I want to show that reservation data on the some table with block color in each cells date according to check in / check out date and the status. This is the example of what I want to show:

[image]

Red color indicates the booking status is Confirmed and check in date is 2019-04-01 and check out date is 2019-04-05. Yellow color indicates the booking status is On Hold and check in date is 2019-04-05 and check out date is 2019-04-09.

This is my code I have done:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Villa ABCD</td>
            <?php for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++) { ?>
            <td><?=$i?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($unit as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($reservation as $row1) : ?>
            <td>Test</td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please anyone help me to solve this problem with PHP, HTML, or JQuery. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid that your question lacks your code and approach to solve the problem...

Comment: Because I don't know how to start with the code. @cdf1982

Comment: Stack-overflow is not a code writing service please make sure to upload some of your code efforts what you have done so far.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I updated my questions with code.

Comment: @Antonio At least try writing out the steps to solving your problem in code comments. Everyone is willing to help you understand, but no one wants to do the work for you.